# Zoom an Image after ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, paintcomponent, graphics2d

I try to create an Image View Program and have a problem in Java Image's zoom in and zoom out :D

I create a JPanel and using BufferedImage to display an image in my computer. After clicking a button, it should be zoom .
But the problem in here that, I overload the method paintComponent() in the JPanel to display a image as I want. After searching in the Google, I think I should use Graphic2D to deal with this problem. Follow on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342233/zoom-in-and-out-of-images-in-java) post, the line

```
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImageWidth , newImageHeight , null);
```

should be put in the overloaded method paintComponent(). Howerver, in my case, I want to zoom the image after clicking a button, so, how can i access to the paintComponent() to do the zoom ??

```
public class MiddlePanel extends JPanel {
private BufferedImage img;
private JButton jbtZoom = new JButton("Zoom");

public MiddlePanel(int width){            

    img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Picture\\pic1.jpg")));

    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,460));        
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img......);
}

public void addComponentActionListener(){
    jbtZoom.addActionListener(new ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(){
            //What should I do in here to zoom the image....
        }
    });
}
```

Thank for your help!

Comment: `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img......);` should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); 
    g.drawImage(img......);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson or simply override `public void paint(Graphics g)` instead of `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)`

Comment: @Vallentin  No!  That is the wrong way to do custom painting in a `JComponent`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your design like so:

- Store in a variable your zoom state and then your
  overridden paintComponent method should look at that variable to
  decide if/how much to zoom.
- Your ActionListener will update the variable then call repaint() on
  the panel.