# Java zoom in on hi-res image without pixelation or losing drawing

Tags: java, swing, zooming

I'm using the approach I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342233/zoom-in-and-out-of-images-in-java) to create zoom in/out functionality for an image labeling application. However, despite dealing with relatively high resolution images (order of 1500x1500 pixels), the scaling method for zoom leads to pixelation. I checked the image in Windows Photo Viewer and I could definitely zoom in without much pixelation until much more than the 200% zoom I have in my code.

If I resize only compared to the original image (i.e. not cascading each resize call), this works just fine (this is what's in the code snippet). But in order to do this, I lose any drawing functionality. Basically, I would like to be able to do the following:

1. Load an image
2. Draw lines/circles/shapes/etc on it
3. Zoom in (maintaining any drawing on the image)
4. Draw more
5. Zoom in/out at will for whatever reasons I need

In summary, the resizing-for-zoom works. It's preserving any additional drawing at each stage of the zoom that I can't seem to get.

Here's a code snippet of my resize function (*heavily* influenced by that answer cited before):

```
private void resizeImage()
{
    int newImgW = (int)(this.zoom * this.imgW);
    int newImgH = (int)(this.zoom * this.imgH);
    BufferedImage resized = new BufferedImage(newImgW, newImgH, originalImage.getType());
    graphics2D = resized.createGraphics();
    graphics2D.drawImage(this.originalImage, 0, 0, newImgW, newImgH, null);
    this.image = resized;
    repaint();
}
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: One step zooming is never a good idea, you need to step down the scaling for better results, [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115950/quality-of-image-after-resize-very-low-java/14116752#14116752)

Comment: Also what is the image you are resizing?  If it is not the original image, but one that you've already resized to zoom out, then zooming in on that will give you a pixelated image.  You have to resize from the ORIGINAL image as per the code you linked too.

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for the step down scaling link. I'll check that out. I can't share the code though, because although I'm writing it and it's hacky and for my use primary, I'm bound by institutional restrictions.

Comment: However @Dijkgraaf's pointed out my obvious mistake which has greatly improved the performance. Thank you both!

Comment: See also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4216123/230513).

Comment: @MadProgrammer: So I'm drawing on the image (remember this is for labeling purposes). Given that I have to resize based on the original image, how do I resize without losing the labels? Is there someway to have all the drawing be done on a mask? That way I can just resize the mask?

Comment: Draw the label to the resized image only

Comment: Well that's the easiest solution. My concern is the scenario where you label at one zoom level, then zoom in to see finer details and label at that zoom level and zoom back out...and so on