# What is the difference between Graphics2D.drawImage (obtained from BufferedImage) and BufferedImage.setRGB() to populate a BufferedImage in Java?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, graphics2d, drawimage

While trying to scale the image drawn on a canvas, I came across `Graphics2D.drawImage(originalImage)` [Graphics2D object obtained from BufferedImage object].

I used it to draw the image into the graphics created from `BufferedImage`, this new image could be now be drawn onto a Graphics object of the Panel/Frame to get a zoomed image.

I populated the original image using `BufferedImage.setRGB`.

So, what is it actually doing? Is it selectively omitting the pixels from the original image?

---

Similar to this code.

```
int newImageWidth = imageWidth * zoomLevel;
int newImageHeight = imageHeight * zoomLevel;
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(newImageWidth , newImageHeight, imageType);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, newImageWidth , newImageHeight , null);
g.dispose();
```

[Original Answer for the above code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9342407/4669984)

Comment: It's not omitting anything. drawImage() is geared towards copying the pixels of an existing image (and not necessarily loaded as a BufferedImage) and also allows scaling as it is a commonly needed feature. setRGB() just copies the pixels out of an array, without genericity and without a scaling option. setRGB() also forces the source pixels to be RGB and thus the destination image to perform relevant conversion if it's not RGB. drawImage() may be using images of the same color model.

Comment: What if I write a smaller image into that scaled BufferedImage graphics2D object same image?

Comment: By default images are drawn at their own size, measured in pixels. If you require them drawn upscaled, the renderer will perform an interpolation and upscale. (Also, you could just try instead of asking)

Comment: You should find all your answers in the Java 2D tutorial, see [Java 2D Rendering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/overview/rendering.html) and [Working with Images](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html) especially.